# EnumWindowsProc() only works first time program is run

Tags: c++, windows, windows-xp, mingw

In my main function, I use the following line `EnumWindows(EnumWindowsProc, NULL)`.  I have the program set itself to run as a scheduled task.  When run manually, it works properly however, when run subsequent times as a scheduled task, this function fails.  If it gets called properly, it never executes the code inside.  I've been scratching my head on this for a while and I can't figure out why.  Someone suggested hwnd might be causing it but didn't know enough to say for sure.  I feel like its an error with the function parameters but don't know what to do that would make it work.  Why does this function fail on the subsequent runs?

```
BOOL CALLBACK EnumWindowsProc(HWND hwnd, LPARAM lParam)
{
    char title[80];
    const char* filepath = somedir; //I checked, this isn't the failure point
    ofstream myfile;
    myfile.open (filepath, ios::app);
    if (IsAltTabWindow(hwnd))
    {
        //myfile.open (filepath, ios::app);  //I was trying opening at different points
        if (myfile.is_open())
        {           
           DWORD pid;
           GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, &pid);
           //GetClassName(hwnd,class_name, sizeof(class_name));
            GetWindowText(hwnd,title, sizeof(title));
           myfile << "Window title: " << title << "        ";
           myfile << "PID: " << pid << endl;
        }
        else 
           MessageBox(NULL, "ERROR", NULL, MB_OK);
        //myfile.close();
    }  

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how the scheduled task is configured, your program may run on a desktop other than the currently logged-on user's interactive desktop; in fact, it may run when no user is logged on at all. In this case, chances are high that there are simply no windows on that desktop, so there's nothing to enumerate.

You want to set up your task to run under your user account, and choose "Run only when user is logged on" option.

Comment: Thank you very much!  I initially set it up to run under system via the command line, and system has no desktop.  I changed it to run under a user account and it works!  I'll have to rewrite some code but at least the bug is gone.